# How do I create a code that creates and prints a list of squares?

Tags: python

I have to write a code that can create and print a list of squares, and am not sure of how to do it. So far all i have is:

```
import string
import cmath


complex = [(i*3j) for i in range(1,21)]
```

I need it to look like this[image]

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. The image seems like question from another blog/site/platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python complex numbers can be created either using direct assignment statement or by using complex () function. I have used the complex function below. Try :

```
complx = []
real_ = []
imag_ = []

for i in range(1,21):
    num = complex((-9*(i**2)),0)
    complx.append(num)
    real_.append(num.real)
    imag_.append(num.imag)
    
print('complx:',complx)
print('real:',real_)
print('Imaginary:',imag_)
```

Output:

```
 complx: 
[(-9+0j), (-36+0j), (-81+0j), (-144+0j), (-225+0j), (-324+0j), (-441+0j), (-576+0j), (-729+0j), (-900+0j), (-1089+0j), (-1296+0j), (-1521+0j), (-1764+0j), (-2025+0j), (-2304+0j), (-2601+0j), (-2916+0j), (-3249+0j), (-3600+0j)]

real: 
[-9.0, -36.0, -81.0, -144.0, -225.0, -324.0, -441.0, -576.0, -729.0, -900.0, -1089.0, -1296.0, -1521.0, -1764.0, -2025.0, -2304.0, -2601.0, -2916.0, -3249.0, -3600.0]

Imaginary: 
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```